# Use findByOrganizerId in spring-data-jpa query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I want to use this as a query method: `findByOrganizerId()` but the "Or" is being interpreted as the `OR` operator! :)
At least - that's what Idea's code highlighting is telling me - that the query will fail.
Will it really fail? And if so, how do I explicitly fix it?
[image]
[image]

Comment: What if you change it to use @Query? Like that: `@Query("select u from #{#entityName} u where u.lastname = ?1")`
`

Comment: That's a bug in IntelliJ's integration, please file an issue with them. Will it really break — no, a quick test case will show that :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** a bug in Spring Data JPA, the query will work as expected.

IntelliJ IDEA, however, is not parsing your method name correctly and thinks the `Or` in `Organizer` is part of an OR statement.

*Spring Data JPA will parse this correctly and execute the correct statement.*

**I have created an issue in Jetbrains' Youtrack bug tracker here:** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165098

Answer (score 0):

`findByOrganizationId()` works fine without any issues, if your database table column name is `organization_id`  (I have tested this).

If your database table column name is `organizationid` (without `_`) `ERROR: column organizati0_.organization_id` does not exist will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

change the name of the variable "organizerId" in your class model to other Synonymous name.
or change var to id_organizer;
 this might fix your Problem

```
Class Meetup{
    @Column(name="organizer_id)
   int id_organizer;

//getter setter

}
```